# ¿Como puedo mostrar texto random en un div con un evento onclick sin que se repita?

Tags: javascript, array, reactjs, algoritmos

Mi idea era hacer un juego de cartas de preguntas y respuestas donde al clickear en un botón te salga una pregunta al azar en un modal, hasta ahí funciona todo. Mi pregunta es ¿Como puedo hacer para que la pregunta que ya salió no vuelva a aparecer? por ejemplo si me sale la pregunta 3, que no vuelva a aparecer en todo el juego.

```
const Arraynaranja = [
    {
        pregunta: "Pregunta1",
        condicion: "Respuesta1",

    },
    {
        pregunta: "Pregunta2",
        condicion: "Respuesta2",
    },
    {
        pregunta: "Pregunta3",
        condicion: "Respuesta3",
    }
  ];

export function Naranja() {
    const [estadoModal1, cambiarEstadoModal1] = useState(false)
    const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);

  function openmodal(){
    changeNaranja();
    abrirmodal1();
  }

  function changeNaranja() {
    let newIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * (Arraynaranja.length - 0) + 0);
    setIndex(newIndex);
  }
  function abrirmodal1(){
    cambiarEstadoModal1(!estadoModal1)
  }

  const audio = new Audio(sonidocarta)


  function abrirysonar(){
    openmodal();
    audio.play()
  }

    return (
        <div>
        <button className="btnnaranja" onClick={abrirysonar}><IoIosBody/></button>

        <ModalNaranja
        estado={estadoModal1}
        cambiarEstado={cambiarEstadoModal1}
        titulo="Prenda"
        
      >
        <Contenido>
          <h1>{Arraynaranja[index].pregunta}</h1>
          <p>{Arraynaranja[index].respuesta}</p>
        </Contenido>
      </ModalNaranja>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Gracias de antemano a todos los que respondan

Comment: Puedes usar un `array` auxiliar, copia del principal, para usarlo y del que ir eliminando las preguntas a medida que vayan saliendo...

Comment: Como podría hacerlo? soy relativamente nuevo en react y es la primera vez que intento una cosa así. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 3):

#### Propuesta

Crear 2 estados uno para el array de `preguntas` (inicializado con el array preguntas) y otro para la pregunta que se va a mostrar `randomCard` (inicializado con carta blanca):

```
const [preguntas, setPreguntas] = React.useState(preguntas_);
const [randomCard, setRandomCard] = React.useState({condicion:'start'});
```

Luego una función de ayuda que obtiene el index aleatorio `newIndex` tal cual la propones y un método `splice` para eliminar del arreglo `preguntas` la carta (pregunta) con index aleatorio:

```
function getRandomCard(){
      let newIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * (preguntas.length - 0) + 0);
      let removed = preguntas.splice(newIndex,1);
      return  removed[0];
    }
```

Además esta función regresa el elemento eliminado, de tal forma que podemos hacer el set de `randomCard` con este elemento eliminado y mostrarlo despues de que el usuario de click en el botón:

```
function clickme(){
      setRandomCard(getRandomCard());
      setPreguntas([...preguntas]);
    }
```

Finalmente hacemos el set del estado `preguntas` con el resto del estado `preguntas` (notese que este arreglo va a cambiar en cada click del botón debido al uso del método `splice` en el mismo `scope`).

Aquí un demo:

```js
const preguntas_ = [
    {
        pregunta: "Pregunta1",
        condicion: "Respuesta1",
    },
    {
        pregunta: "Pregunta2",
        condicion: "Respuesta2",
    },
    {
        pregunta: "Pregunta3",
        condicion: "Respuesta3",
    },
     {
        pregunta: "Pregunta0",
        condicion: "Respuesta0",
    },
    {
        pregunta: "Pregunta4",
        condicion: "Respuesta4",
    },
    {
        pregunta: "Pregunta5",
        condicion: "Respuesta5",
    }
  ];
  


function App(){
  const [preguntas, setPreguntas] = React.useState(preguntas_);
  const [randomCard, setRandomCard] = React.useState({condicion:'start'});
  
  function getRandomCard(){
  let newIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * (preguntas.length - 0) + 0);
  let removed = preguntas.splice(newIndex,1);
  return  removed[0];
}


function clickme(){
  setRandomCard(getRandomCard());
  setPreguntas([...preguntas]);
}
return (
  <React.Fragment>
    <div style={{ border: '1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)', width:'100px'}}>{randomCard.condicion}</div>
    <button onClick={clickme}>Intercambio de carta</button>
    <div style={{ border: '1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)'}}>{preguntas.map(e=>e.condicion)}</div>
  </React.Fragment>
)
}


ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin ></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin ></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Método [Splice](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp)

Comment: Me ayudo un montón esto. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

Puedes tener un arreglo o un objeto en el que guardes o marques los índices de las preguntas que ya aparecieron.

Para facilitar la generación del número aleatorio, genera una lista con los índices que sí están disponibles y el número aleatorio en base a su longitud.

Algo así:

```js
const preguntas = [
    {
        pregunta: "Pregunta1",
        condicion: "Respuesta1",
    },
    {
        pregunta: "Pregunta2",
        condicion: "Respuesta2",
    },
    {
        pregunta: "Pregunta3",
        condicion: "Respuesta3",
    }
  ];

yaPreguntado = {}

function indicesDisponibles(){
    return preguntas.map((pregunta, indice) => yaPreguntado[indice] ? -1 : indice).filter(indice => indice >= 0) 
}

function elegirAleatorio(arreglo){
    indice = Math.floor(Math.random() * indices.length)
    return arreglo[indice]
}

function mostrarPregunta(){
    indices = indicesDisponibles()
    newIndex = elegirAleatorio(indices)

    yaPreguntado[newIndex] = true
    console.log(preguntas[newIndex])
}

console.log(indicesDisponibles())
mostrarPregunta()
console.log(indicesDisponibles())
mostrarPregunta()
console.log(indicesDisponibles())
mostrarPregunta()
```

Solo resta adaptarlo a tu código.